# Parse values from the JSON returned by URL of Google Place API

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-api-nodejs-client, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am creating a bot using dialogflow-fulfillment, and I am using Google Place API to pull additional information about hospitals.

I have made a dummy response, for the sake of example, that is returned by Google Place API, here is the link: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c2b9f9e3000007000abafe3

```
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "140 George St, The Rocks NSW 2000, Australia",
         "name" : "Museum of Contemporary Art Australia",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 3492,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105784220914426417603/photos\"\u003eKeith Chung\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAaGaCX-kivNEaJ-z97AduTYgW3d98uv53-8skNrS1k1GTgOtiQ1-Z2gfWJydrpkrshuV_kHPKizl088dezEJgIxYGoTWqtJgah-u_I46qNNYMfUbk8LKBZqxzkHyIL1nWEhBO6lPa0NgvlyLGBrXpXFPUGhT0lAUj_oCiOWV2MEYdBeKf-kTtgg",
           "width" : 4656
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I need to parse values of my choice from the JSON returned by Google Place API. For example, If I had to parse value of `'name'` from the JSON above using Python, I would do this:

```
import requests, json
api_key = ''
r = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name&key=' + api_key)
x = r.json()
y = x['candidates']
print(y[0]['name'])
```

Above code for the job is lucid and works perfectly. Considering my inexperience in Nodejs, would you please let me know something similar in Nodejs to parse the value, for instance, the value of `'name'`?

Your valuable reply will encourage me.

P.S: Humbly, the question involves first making a call to Google Place API and then parsing values from the returned JSON. Please follow the steps given in Python code above for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Get the API response in an async HTTP request (there are tons of npm libraries like `request` to help you automatically set headers etc), then use standard library `JSON.parse(body)` to get an plain JavaScript object which contains a structured representation of the API response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse